# Office 365 - Sharepoint - Possible individual access?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, licence

I'd like to get an equivalent of the "Office 365 Business Premium" offer but for a personal use meaning that I don't want to create a company for that (it's just for some personal projects, between 3-5 persons...). Is there a possibility to subscribe to this offer as an individual? Or is there some kind of equivalent with a Sharepoint access (did not find it on Microsoft sites) for personal use?

Money for this subscription is not the issue. I just don't want to create any kind of company just for that matter...

Answer (score 0):

The different plans can be found [here](https://products.office.com/en-gb/compare-all-microsoft-office-products?tab=2). You pay per user, so this will work for you. You don't have to create an company to use this.

edit: changed link to go directly to the 'For Business' tab

Comment: But those plans are not including Sharepoint it seems.

Comment: You need to click over to the 'For Business' tab on the page - sorry I forgot to mention that